Area of shaded curve integral negative thus incorrect
Find the area of the shaded figure, integral.

Integral:
$$\int_{a}^{b} (x^2-4) \, dx$$
Limitations:
$y=x^2-4$
$x^2-4=0$
$x^2=4$
$x = \pm \sqrt{4} = 2$
The limitation I am able to find from the figure,$\left[-2, 2\right]$.
Integrating:
$\int_{-2}^{2} (x^2-4) \, dx = \left[\frac{x^3}{3} - 4x\right]_{-2}^{2}$
Applying:
$F(2)-F(-2) = -\frac{16}{3} - \frac{16}{3}$
$=-\frac{32}{3}$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $\frac{32}{3}$, mine is negative.

you found the signed area, but the problem asked for the area

@J.W.Tanner I tried to calculate the shaded area between $\left[-2, 2\right]$.

I think the discrepancy here is just about terminology. "Area" is by definition positive. The fact that your answer is negative means that it is not an area. If it wasn't immediately clear to you from reading the question that the answer should be positive, this is a vocabulary issue, not anything about integrals.

Consider that the integral is a kind of a sum, and the values $ x^2 - 4 $ you have are all negative. Hence, the sum (integral) you get is also negative. Also, think about what happens if the integral is taken over a range where the function is both positive and negative, e.g. $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} (\sin x) dx $ . What's the integral in that case, and what's the total area between the sine and the x axis?

The integral is correct, but it doesn't compute the area of the shaded region. If $f(x) \geq 0$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ computes the area of region satisfying $a\leq x \leq b$ and $0 \leq y \leq f(x)$.
In general, if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b (g(x)-f(x))\,dx$ measures the area of the region satisfying $0 \leq x \leq b$ and $f(x) \leq y \leq g(x)$. If you set $g(x) = 0$ you will get the right area.

Hi, we have one curve, thus $f() - g()$ does not apply here.

@SaraJönsson:  In the above example, we have the shaded region between $y=0$ and $y = x^2 - 4$ on the interval $x \in [-2,2]$.  So one "curve" is flat, but it does figure in the problem formulation.

Who said anything about a curve? There are two functions, however.

@MatthewLeingang Where? The two points on x-axis.

One of the functions is your original $f$. The other is $g(x) = 0$. The graph of $g$ is the $x$-axis.

@MatthewLeingang You are correct in the answer above as confirmed in this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/NoFAI4j5DPw?si=QKTv4UCq4Dkp0Y3p, the Integral can be Negative, but the Area is Positive.

I'm glad you figured it out!


Shaded area=$\int_{-2}^2 (4-x^2)dx=\frac{32}{3} $

The area is, by definition, a positive number. The integral doesn't always give the area between the curve and the $x$ axis. If the curve is below the $x$ axis, it gives the negative of the area. So all you had to do was take the absolute value.
If part of the curve is above the axis and part is below, you have to break it up into pieces, take the integral of each piece, then take the absolute value of each result, and add them.

In this case, you need to take the absolute value of the integral because the filled region is located UNDER the abscissa axis, not above it.
So, the correct answer is $|-\frac{32}{3}| = \bf\frac{32}{3}$.

But you did not explain why the filled region under the x axis would result in a negative area. It is because the integral computes signed area.
